# Custom IEnumerable implementation fails for setting with IEnumerable

Tags: c#, interface, operator-overloading, ienumerable

I'm trying to build a custom type which implements `IEnumerable<T>` as I need a custom type-converter. Currently I have this:

```
[TypeConverter(typeof(StringListTypeConverter))]
public class StringList<T> : IEnumerable<T>, IStringConvertible
{
    // ... implementations of IEnumerable<T>
}
```

However, when I change my old properties types from `IEnumerable<string> MyProp` to `StringList<T> MyProp` I get errors when those properties are set e.g.

```
MyProp = new[]{"test"};
MyProp = SomeListArray.Select(s => $"{s}_test");
```

I get the error:

> 'System.String[]' to 'StringList<String>'
>
> 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<String>' to 'StringList<String>'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Note as of questions from the comment. I want to pass an `IEnumerable` of a type `T` via `QueryString` to my api-server. To keep the URL as short as possible I want only on parameter `?MyProp=test,anotherstring,evenMoreString&MyIntProp=1,4,12,134`.
On server-side I want to convert this string back to an `IEnumerable<T>` (in case of the example `QueryString` to an `IEnumerable<string>` and `IEnumerable<int>`).

I already tried to add an implicit operator

```
public static implicit operator StringList<T>(IEnumerable<T> elements)
{
    return new StringList<T>(elements);
}
```

but this is forbidden from the C# specs. So, what can I do to only change the property's type instead of the whole code where they are set (as this is quite a large refactoring)?

Comment: Why don't you just add explicit cast?

Comment: @S.Petrosov, as this would mean to refactor all the code where those `IEnumerables` are set, which I would like to avoid.

Comment: Why type named StringList has type parameter T? Shouldn't it just be `class StringList : IEnumerable<string>`?

Comment: You could write a LINQ extension method like .ToStringList() as is .ToList() https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/how-to-add-custom-methods-for-linq-queries

Comment: @Evk, its named so because it's used to send an enumertion of `T` to the server as list of strings (to keep the url short). On server-side it should be reverted to the concrete `IEnumerable<T>` as of `T` could be string, Guid, int or even an enum...

Comment: @Madenis, this would also mean to refactor all occurrences where such a property is set

Comment: So StringList<Guid> is list of guids and not strings?

Comment: @Evk, yes it can be of any non-complex type

Comment: You can define conversion `implicit operator StringList<T>(T[] elements)`, this will help with first case (where you assign an array to this property). Unfortunately for interfaces like `IEnumerable` you cannot do that, as you already discovered.

Answer (score 0):

> MyProp = new[]{"test"};

If your `MyProp` property type is `StringList<T>`, you cannot assign an array instance to it, because Array does not derive from it.

> MyProp = SomeListArray.Select(s => $"{s}_test");

Almost the same. LINQ returns IEnumerable, which does not derive from StringList. You cannot assign the base type object to variable of derived type.

You can add the extension method and use it whenever you need `StringList<T>` object:

```
public static class StringListExtensions
{
    public static StringList<T> ToStringList<T>(this IEnumerable<T> elements)
    {
        return new StringList<T>();
    }
}

MyProp = SomeListArray.Select(s => $"{s}_test").ToStringList();
```

Comment: This would also mean to refactor each and every occurrence of such a setter. Would be the same for explicit casts.

Comment: Can you leave your property type IEnumerable<T>, and just call the extension method or cast it whenever you need StringList<T>? If you try to avoid refactoring, and your code works well with IEnumerable<T> property, just leave it, and use StringList only if it is required.